# Permutations. Let $C, B$ be from $S_n$. Prove that $C^{-1}B^{-1}CB$ is in $A_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let it be $C, B$ from $S_n$. Prove that $C^{-1}B^{-1}CB$ is from $A_n$.

Comment: Caution: This user has posted many PSQs recently, a lot of which have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sign homomorphism $\sigma\colon S_n\to\{-1,1\}$. Then
$$
\sigma(C^{-1}B^{-1}CB)=\sigma(C)^{-1}\sigma(B)^{-1}\sigma(C)\sigma(B)=1
$$
because $\{-1,1\}$ is abelian.

Comment: Woow. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this really likely to be of help to the OP in any other case than this being homework?

Comment: Yes, it's very helpful for my exercise.